# ionic2 app reverse geocoding show wrong result

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, reverse-geocoding

On a button press I'm populating textfield with location address.

Below is my code to get current location and then get address from latitude and longitude.

```
useLocation(){
        let loc: any = {lat: 60.1676, lon: 24.9359};

 getCurrentLocation().then((position: Geoposition) => {
     let loca: any =  {lat: position.coords.latitude, lon: position.coords.longitude};
            let req: GeocoderRequest = { position: loca }
                Geocoder.geocode(req).then((results)=>{
                        if (results.length) {
                            var result = results[0];
                            var position = result.position;
                            var address = [
                            result.subThoroughfare || "",
                            result.thoroughfare || "",
                            result.locality || "",
                            result.adminArea || "",
                            result.postalCode || "",
                            result.country || ""].join(", ");
                            this.profile.address = address;
                        } else {
                            alert("Not found");
                        }
                })

 }, () => {
 });
}
```

Above code is returning address of somewhere in Algeria, while in variable `loca` i'm getting lat and lng of my current location which is Karachi, Pakistan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think issue is with the latlng you are sending to geocoder,

```
    getCurrentLocation().then((position: Geoposition) => {
             let loca: any =  {lat: position.coords.latitude, lon: position.coords.longitude},
                 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loca.lat, loca.lng),
  request = {
        latLng: latlng
      };
                        geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results.length) {
                                    var result = results[0];
                                    //do stuff here
                            }
                            else {
                               console.log('Cannot determine address of this location.');
                            }
                        })

         }
```

Comment: [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
This error is appearing on geocoder.geocode(...) line

Comment: no value in `latlng` after this line s executed. latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loca.lat, loca.lng),

Comment: There should be value in latlng. are you getting loca.lat and loca.lng

Comment: You can check your latlng here - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true